# Young Claire flashback scenes in season 6 House of Cards

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-cards

What is the meaning of young Claire flashback scenes in season 6 House of Cards? It is never stated explicitly nor explained. The scenes also don't seem to have any direct correlation to any other that surround them. Like, for example, the first of a series, where Claire is assaulted by a group of boys - makes no sense in the context. One could argue that the scenes are just to present Claire's past as this is finally "her turn", however that appears too shallow given that the entire season has this tale about an evil witch vibe.